# If ‘Eid prayer and Friday prayer (salaatul-Jumu’ah) fall on the same day, what are the options?

Tags: salat, eid, jumuah

لسَّلاَمُ عَلَيْكُمْ وَرَحْمَةُ اللهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ

If ‘Eid prayer and Friday prayer (salaatul-Jumu’ah) fall on the same day, what are the options? because some persons only do eid prayer in my neighbors.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first day of Eid (Fitr or Adha) happen to be a Friday. Then you can:

- Either pray Salat Eid **and** Dhuhr prayer, without having to pray Jumu'ah,
- Or just pray Jumu'ah prayer,
- And of course he can pray both Eid and Jumu'ah, and it is good to do that.

Evidence that the Jumu'ah prayer is not required if one prayed Eid are this hadith:

> It was narrated that Iyas bin Abi Ramlah said:
>   "I heard Mu'awiyah asking Zaid bin Arqam: 'Did you attend two 'Eids with the Messenger of Allah ()?' He said: 'Yes; he prayed 'Eid at the beginning of the day then he granted a concession with regard to jumu'ah.'" (Hasan)
>
> أَخْبَرَنَا عَمْرُو بْنُ عَلِيٍّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ مَهْدِيٍّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا إِسْرَائِيلُ، عَنْ عُثْمَانَ بْنِ الْمُغِيرَةِ، عَنْ إِيَاسِ بْنِ أَبِي رَمْلَةَ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ مُعَاوِيَةَ، سَأَلَ زَيْدَ بْنَ أَرْقَمَ أَشَهِدْتَ مَعَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم عِيدَيْنِ قَالَ نَعَمْ صَلَّى الْعِيدَ مِنْ أَوَّلِ النَّهَارِ ثُمَّ رَخَّصَ فِي الْجُمُعَةِ ‏.‏
>
> [[Sunan An-nasai]](http://sunnah.com/nasai/19/36).

Also there are many other evidences in these two pages  [[1]](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/109323), [[2]](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=&Option=FatwaId&Id=15442).